# SQL Server Compact Edition to SQL Azure Synchronization using Sync Framework 2.1

Tags: sql-server-ce, azure-sql-database, microsoft-sync-framework

Need example to synchronize SQL Server Compact Edition to SQL Azure Synchronization using Sync Framework 2.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the documentation that comes with the framework, that contains a walkthrough/tutorial.

here's the online version: [Tutorial: Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617382.aspx)

sample apps:

[Database Sync: SQL Server and SQL Compact 2-Tier](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-Sync-SQL-Server-de6c8ff8)

[Database Sync: SQL Server and SQL Compact N-Tier with WCF](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-Sync-SQL-Server-7e88adab)

Comment: it's works thanks, but i do some modifications in the azure connection string (Data Source={machine}.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog={db_name};User ID={db_user}@{machine};Password={password};Connection Timeout=3000;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;)